# Qual a ordem de retorno da função "find" do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django

Eu tenho uma aplicação em Django que usa esse widget: https://github.com/ExoticObjects/django-better-filter-widget/

[image: dj]

Na linha 6 do arquivo better-filter-widget.js o plugin executa o seguinte:

```
orig_input.find('option:selected').each(function(i, opt)
```

Eu precisava que os elementos fossem inseridos na coluna "Selected Children" exatamente na ordem de seleção e não na ordem alfabética.

A função "find" retorna os elementos na ordem em que eles aparecem no `document`?

Comment: O find pega pela ordem dos elementos. Ele não reorganiza por nenhum critério. O plugin que vc está usando recria uma lista de elementos cada vez que vc seleciona um item, e como a primeira lista está em ordem alfabética, a segunda lista dinâmica tb ficará.

Answer (score 1):

O `.find` retorna os elementos na ordem que eles estão no DOM. O plugin que está usando recria uma lista de `div`'s (`Selected Children`) cada vez que você seleciona um elemento na primeira lista (`Available Children`). Como os nomes na primeira lista estão em ordem alfabética, consequentemente a segunda lista também ficará na mesma ordem, porque o `.find` assim os encontra no DOM.

O que você pode fazer é adicionar alguns códigos no plugin para chegar ao resultado que deseja. Para isso é preciso adicionar um atributo ao item adicionado para que possamos depois reorganizar a segunda lista. Esse atributo seria um *dataset* com um valor numérico representando a ordem em que o item foi adicionado, por exemplo:

```
var ordem = 1;
// adiciona ao item o atributo data-add = ordem;
ordem++; // incrementa +1 para o próximo item
```

Assim, o último item adicionado sempre terá um valor maior que o anterior. Esses valores serão usados para que possamos reorganizar as divs da segunda lista.

Altere a função `selectItem()` e declare a variável `ordem` com o valor `1`:

```
var ordem = 1;
function selectItem(){
   // BFWTimer.start(arguments.callee.name);
   var selected_item = $(this);
   var selected_id = selected_item.data('id');
   selected_item.addClass('selected');
   // if (had_focus) filter_input.focus(); // to bring keyboard back on mobile
   // select item in the hidden input
   orig_input.find('option[value='+selected_id+']').attr(
   {
      'selected':'selected',
      'data-add': ordem
   });
   ordem++;
   updateSelectedDisplay();
   toast('Added '+ selected_item.text());
   // BFWTimer.report(arguments.callee.name);
}
```

Agora altere a função `updateSelectedDisplay()` inserindo um código que irá reorganizar as divs pelo valor do atributo `data-add` adicionado:

```
function updateSelectedDisplay(){
   // BFWTimer.start(arguments.callee.name);
   selected_items.html('');
   orig_input.find('option[selected]').each(function(i, opt){
      opt = $(opt);
      var item = $('<div class="item item-selected" data-add="'+ opt.data("add") +'" data-id="'+opt.attr('value')+'"><span class="action-icon action-icon-minus">-</span>'+opt.text()+'</div>');
      selected_items.append( item );
      item.click(deselectItem);
   });

   // reorganiza divs pelo data-add crescente
   selected_items.find('div.item').detach().sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.dataset.add - b.dataset.add;
   }).appendTo(selected_items);


   // BFWTimer.report(arguments.callee.name);
}
```